# why my merge sort program is not working?

Tags: python, algorithm, mergesort

Why is my merge sort program not working?

```py
def merge(a, p, q, r):
    n1 = (q - p) + 1
    n2 = r - q
    L = [0] * n1
    M = [0] * n2

    for i in range(n1):
        L[i] = a[i]

    for j in range(n2):
        M[j] = a[j]

    i = 0
    j = 0

    for k in range(p, r):
        if L[i] <= M[j]:
            a[k] = L[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            a[k] = M[j]
            j += 1

def merge_sort(a, p, r):
    if len(a) <= 1:
        print('list has only one element')
    else:
        q = len(a) // 2
        merge_sort(a, p, q)
        merge_sort(a, q + 1, r)
        merge(a, p, q, r)

        
a = [3,41,52,26,38,57,9,49]
merge_sort(a, 0, len(a) - 1)
for _ in range(len(a)):
    print('%d', a[_])
```

Comment: I'm not a python person (this is python, right?), but it seems that both the initial `i` and `j` ranges start at zero, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- The initialization loops for the slices are incorrect. The index into `a` should start at `p` and `q+1` respectively. Change them to:

  ```
    for i in range(n1):
        L[i] = a[p+i]

    for j in range(n2):
        M[j] = a[q+1+j]
  ```

  Or simply write:

  ```
    L = a[p..q+1]
    M = b[q+1..r+1]
  ```

  Which make it obvious that `q` and `r` should be excluded bounds rather than included.
- The merging loop is incorrect: the range should be `range(p, r+1)` and once one of the temporary arrays is exhausted, comparing `L[i] <= M[j]` refers to an element beyond the boundary of either `L` or `M`.
- `q` is not computed correctly in `merge_sort`: it should be `q = (p + r) // 2`
- the test `if len(a) <= 1:` is incorrect, you should instead test if the slice has at least 2 elements and do nothing if it does not:

  ```
    if p < r:
        q = (p + r) // 2
        merge_sort(a, p, q)
        merge_sort(a, q + 1, r)
        merge(a, p, q, r)
  ```

Here is a modified version with excluded upper bounds:

```py
def merge(a, p, q, r):
    L = a[p..q]
    M = a[q..r]

    i = 0
    j = 0

    for k in range(p, r):
        if j >= len(M) or (i < len(L) and L[i] <= M[j]):
            a[k] = L[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            a[k] = M[j]
            j += 1

def merge_sort(a, p, r):
    if r - p > 1:
        q = p + (r - p) // 2
        merge_sort(a, p, q)
        merge_sort(a, q, r)
        merge(a, p, q, r)

        
a = [3,41,52,26,38,57,9,49]
merge_sort(a, 0, len(a))
for _ in range(len(a)):
    print('%d', a[_])
```